# Not able to form correct regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I've a string like:

> `{\"clearExistingTargeting\":\"Yes\",\"campaignid\":\"[CampaignID]\",\"targeting\":{\"appsitetargeting\":{\"[filterout]\":{\"site\":\"www.google.com\",\"app\":\"com.facebook\"},\"filterin\":{\"site\":\"www.gmail.com\",\"app\":\"com.lw.sdk\"}}}}`

I want to extract all those string which are enclosed in `[]` like `[CampaignID]` and `[filterout]`, I am trying with regular expression - 
`(\\[.*\\])` but its giving the output

```
[CampaignID]\",\"targeting\":{\"appsitetargeting\":{\"[filterout]
```

Its matching from the first `[` but ending with the last `]`.

Comment: make it lazy using :- `(\\[.*?\\])` or `([^]]*)`

Comment: @rock321987  Output is: {"clearExistingTargeting":"Yes","campaignid":"[CampaignID

","targeting":{"appsitetargeting":{"[filterout

":{"site":"www.google.com","app":"com.facebook"},"filterin":{"site":"www.gmail.com","app":"com.lw.sdk"}}}}

Comment: access the first capturing group..

Comment: @rock321987 worked with (\\[.*?\\]) Thanks a lot